# How to use a purchased web template for an existing Django web development

Tags: django

My team and I are working on a project that involves a landing page and dashboard for the users after their login. We have more or less completed the functions of the webpages with very basic styling using bootstrap. We purchased a html template from the web and would like to 'transfer' what we have onto the new template so that it will look professional without us having to style everything from scratch.

I have very basic knowledge of the template inheritance system and thus have much difficulty using the purchased template into our work.

I would like to seek some guidance to how I can/should proceed to use the purchased template. For example should I work on the base.html using the purchased index.html file from the purchased template and how I should go about doing so.

I'm lost in how I should start so any tips will definitely be of a great help.

Comment: This is far too broad a question. There's no "set" way to do this. It totally depends on the template in question. You need to read through the [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) and get more familiar with it. Then make use of blocks and inheritance via the `include` template tag.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony he just need how to get started right ?

Answer (score 0):

So the workaround is include all the css and js in static folder

```
static
    css
    js 
templates
    landing
        homepage.html
    base.html
```

copy all the index.html to base.html and remote inside body content and place it in homepage.html. Now

**homepage.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
paste all inside body contents here
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Note: Make your view return to `landing/homepage.html`